# How do i configure a playwright test in java to allow retest fails in surefire and produce a maven-cucumber-reporting report?

Tags: java, maven, playwright, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm testing using Playwright trying to get the maven-surefire-plugin to re-test failed tests and maven-cucumber-reporting plugin to produce a report after all testing is carried out when ran from command line.

I can get the cucumber report to create, but i cannot get test to re-run on a fail.

I have tried re-ordering the POM file and trying to get both plugins to run on the verify command and tried various configurations within the file. See POM below

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>maven</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>16</source>
                <target>16</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <rerunFailingTestsCount>3</rerunFailingTestsCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>Supersonic Report</projectName>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <outputDirectory>../Reports/Supersonic/TestReports/</outputDirectory>
                        <inputDirectory>../Reports/Supersonic/JsonOutput/</inputDirectory>
                        <skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                        <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                        <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried moving the surefire and cucumber reporting executions between plugin management and the plugin section at the end but if the cucumber-reporting plugin is not in the last section it doesn't create a report.

Any ideas on how to retest fails using these plugins ?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this one out? I am in exactly the same situation :)